# What and where are my errors in this POM?

Tags: pom.xml

I have tried to whrite a pom on sample application but I get a error in dependencies.
I read https://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html and https://maven.apache.org/community.html realatives article, I still can not find it.

But When I look at my pom, it contains all elements which are included in the https://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html that I need.

Given below is the pom, of my application, I can't see the error. Any body colud sugest something.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
For artifact {practica:app01:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {practica:app01:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
    pom.xml /app01  line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:${org.springframework-Version}

Thanks in advance for any help on clarifying this issue.

my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>practica</groupId>
    <artifactId>app01</artifactId>
    <name>app01</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Host for deploy-->
        <bb-host>127.0.0.1</bb-host>

        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.2</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.12</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-Version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>spi-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Allows the routes to be run via 'mvn camel:run' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you get any specific error messages? Also, what Maven command do you use to build your project?

Comment: This is the pom that can't found the error. I tried to search, I may be tired,  but I can't see it.